# Redmind ckeditor plugin : do not show toolbar

Tags: redmine-plugins

I am new to Redmine and I search though the internet but found no help!!!

I followed the instructions here: [Source](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine-ckeditor)

And it shows me a richtext editor without toolbar.

My Redmine version is 3.1.0 and CKEditor plugin is 1.1.2

I tried to reinstall CKEditor many times but I still have the same problem.

I want to enable the toolbar!

Please help

Comment: I can't upload image due to a new member i think. I will contribute more to stackoverflow to have this permission (if i am not wrong)

Comment: Post link of image here, I will do it for you, by the way it should be edit to your question and you should be able to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It's about the "Toolbar can collapse" checkbox which is checked. I uncheck it and the toolbar was show.

@Admin or Mod: Please close this question.